# Oracle SQL*Plus: disable processing of '@' (at sign) metacharacter

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Oracle SQL*Plus interprets the at sign, `@` as a command to [run a SQL script](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12002.htm).

I have a `.sql` script which contains the `@` character in comments, such as:

```
create or replace package mypkg
as

  /*
    Procedure foo

    @param bar blah blah blah
  */
  procedure foo(bar varchar2);

end mypkg;
/
```

How can I disable processing of the at sign? I am already using `SET DEFINE OFF` and `SET SQLPREFIX OFF` to disable unwanted processing of metacharacters.

Comment: My script is in a file named `MYPKG.sql`, and I run it from `sqlplus` using `@MYPKG.sql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this commenting notation for years so I was surprised this was an issue.
I make use of the package "pldoc" http://sourceforge.net/projects/pldoc/?source=directory to generate documentation. The standard way of commenting is like this (like javadoc):

```
create or replace package mypkg
as

  /**
  * Procedure foo
  * 
  * @param bar blah blah blah
  */
  procedure foo(bar varchar2);

end mypkg;
/

me@XE> @mypkg.sql

Package created.
```

Comment: I see. The asterisk symbol, `*`, prevents SQL*Plus from interpreting the at sign. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of ways to disable the START command (which includes the @ and @@ commands).

One way is to place an appropriate entry in PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE (which is actually a synonym for SYSTEM.PRODUCT_PRIVS).  To do so perform an INSERT similar to

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE
  (PRODUCT,     USERID, ATTRIBUTE, CHAR_VALUE)
VALUES
  ('SQL*Plus', 'DUMMY', 'START',   'DISABLED')
```

This requires that the userid you're using have INSERT privileges on PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE.

The second way is to use the -RESTRICT option with an argument of 3 when starting SQL*Plus.  This may be simpler, but there are additional commands disabled by -RESTRICT 3 which you may need to have enabled, such as SPOOL.  See the section titled "RESTRICT Option" at [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch3.htm#i1169742) for more info.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I am running the script using the `@` command, so disabling and/or restricting the `START` is not an option here, sorry. I just wish to stop `sqlplus` from interpreting metacharacters inside PL/SQL source files.

Comment: @DaniloPiazzalunga - one other thing you could do would be to use DBMS_UTILITY.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT to execute the CREATE PACKAGE and CREATE PACKAGE BODY statements - but then you'd have to have an interface other than SQL*Plus to do *that* in, which gets you right back to the problem you're facing.